# How can I prove to someone that the inventor of an USPTO-granted patent is actually me?

Tags: inventorship, inventor, identifying

What are the reliable ways to justify to a third party that the inventor of an USPTO granted patent (i.e. linked in google patents) is actually me (given that I am the real inventor)?

Update: As Eric suggested in answer that innovators location mentioned in the patent can be one way. However, what will happen when multiple inventors from same place and same name start claiming ownership of any patent?

Comment: You are listed on the front page of the patent ?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite thanks. But the name can be of other person who has same name of mine.

Comment: Are you also the owner? If do you should have a ribboned version, if US.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I am the inventor and the assignee and the owner is my company for which I work.

Comment: One the fewplaces this would really matter is in an infringement action taken in court by the owner. To ask what proof might hold up in court I would ask on law.stack exchange.com.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite yes, i think it is a valid question. Please share if you find anything informative. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite do you have any update from law.stack exchange?

Comment: I meant that if I were you I  would ask it on that site. You can ask there.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite ok. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patent office public records will show the list of inventors and their city and country. In public PAIR one can see more information including the name and contact data for the attorney or agent, if any were used. You could ask your attorney to respond to someone verifying that you are the person named on the patent. If this were needed to be established in a court of law testimony by the attorney of record might or might not be definitive.

In a comment you mention the assignee is the company you work for. In that case there should  not be co-inventors or people with the same name as an inventor trying to claim ownership.  The company owns it - other than bragging rights it is now irrelevant who the inventors are.

Comment: Although in this case the company is the assignee, the question has been edited to ask what happens if two like named people from the same town claim ownership of a patent. Let's just use the example of two John Smiths from New York City. I'm assuming there is some establishment of ownership that is more than just name and town. Perhaps an address of the assignee. Looking at Pair, I'm assuming your comment about consulting with the attorney or agent would suffice. The entire contact info for the Attorney/Agent is in Pair.

Comment: Is it possible to not publicly disclose the city and country of the inventor(s)? Alternately can a corporation be the inventor (so the company) and not a private person?

Comment: In the US people are inventors.

Answer (score 2):

For my patents, my name and town (town, state and country) I live at are listed on the front of the patents. This is true for at least US and European patents. There may not be another person with your name in the same location. Try a Google search to see. For me, I'm the only person with my name in my town.

Comment: Yes but that may not be a reliable method to confirm for many inventors. No other more reliable method?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the problem. Is someone else pretending to be the inventor of your patent?

Comment: I just want to understand the process. What will happen when multiple inventors from  same place and same name start claiming ownership of any patent?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan I can't help you further. All my patents were while working for others so I have no access to communications with patent offices. I did check Public Pair to see if there was any additional identifying info and didn't find any. Perhaps you could clarify your question with your last comment.

Comment: thanks for your time. I have updated the post.

Comment: @EricS what happens if these info related to the inventor or to the applicant are outdated? E.g., you enter the city and state and country where you were living 2 years ago, for example to not disclose your current location?

Comment: @Pa_ So far as I know, nothing happens. If I move, the patents listing me and my town of residence stay the same. To my knowledge no one is claiming to be both me and the inventor on my patents. One could always track down the attorney listed with the patent to prove who is who.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the reliable ways to justify to a third party that the inventor of an USPTO granted patent (i.e. linked in google patents) is actually me (given that I am the real inventor)?

The inventor of an USPTO granted patent can provide a patent certificate.

From https://www.upcounsel.com/patent-certificate ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20220109024646/https://www.upcounsel.com/patent-certificate)):

> When Will I Receive My Patent Certificate?
>
> Once your patent application has been approved by the USPTO, you'll receive a Notice of Allowance. Then, you must pay your issue fee before subsequently receiving your Issue Notification. The patent certificate with the USPTO seal will be mailed on the issue date.
>
> If you have designated a [patent attorney or agent](https://www.upcounsel.com/blog/hire-patent-attorney-patent-agent) as your power of attorney, he or she will receive the certificate as the attorney of record and should forward it to you. If no power of attorney has been designated, the intellectual property (IP) owner will receive the patent certificate at the address indicated on the application datasheet.
>
> The Certificate Series plaque is a reproduction of the patent certificate. Extra patent certificates can be ordered from [USPTO](http://uspto.gov/) for $25 each. Each patent certificate contains the USPTO seal and director signature; you can also request it to include the names of the inventors and a corporate logo at no additional charge.

-> https://www.uspto.gov/patents/apply/checking-application-status/order-certified-copies